# Extract string inside specific pattern [...] in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a column, Industry which looks like below, I would like to create a new column called Code which only contains the character that appear in the [...], THEN I wish to create a new column Industry_2 which contains all the characters but witHout the [...] so my results would look like below.

| Industry | Code | Industry_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total, all industries |  | Total, all industries |
| Agriculture [11] | [11] | Agriculture |
| Manufacturing [31-33] | [31-33] | Manufacturing |

Answer (score 3):

Use `tidyr::separate` with a look-ahead for the delimiter to keep the `[` in the second string.

```r
df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Total, all industries", "Agriculture [11]",
                        "Manufacturing [31-33]"))

library(tidyr)
separate(df, Industry,
         sep = " (?=\\[)", 
         into = c("Industry_2", "Code"),
         remove = FALSE)
```

output

```r
               Industry            Industry_2    Code
1 Total, all industries Total, all industries    <NA>
2      Agriculture [11]           Agriculture    [11]
3 Manufacturing [31-33]         Manufacturing [31-33]
```

Comment: Regex lookahead fixed the problem I was facing

Answer (score 1):

If it is on the end of the line you could use gsub:

```
 dataset$Code = gsub(".*\\[", "\\[", dataset$Industry)
 dataset$Industry_2 = gsub("\\[.*", "", dataset$Industry)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
df[c('code', "industry_2")] <- tstrsplit(df$Industry, " (?=\\[)", perl = TRUE) |> rev()

#                Industry    code            industry_2
# 1 Total, all industries    <NA> Total, all industries
# 2      Agriculture [11]    [11]           Agriculture
# 3 Manufacturing [31-33] [31-33]         Manufacturing
```